# Calculate Row and Column

Tags: math, coordinates, graphing

Is there a formula or algorithm used to calculate row and column positions of random x and y points on a coordinate system?

The entire coordinate system can be skewed in both the x and y at an unknown angle, so the first row would be considered to be the top most row of x and y coordinates.  There can also be missing x and y coordinates as well within the entire array.

[Row and Column Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6n1e.png)

I have considered trying a concave hull algorithm, then connecting each end point with a line, and finally getting each point closest to the lines but this seems overly complicated.

Comment: This can't be done univocally without additional assumptions, which you left unstated. In the given example, consider the dot that's currently assigned to the bottom position of Column 2. How did you determine that it's in fact the last dot in column 2 vs. the last dot in Column 1? If you shift that dot to the left, at which point will it count as Column 1 instead of Column 2?

Comment: Hey Mark, I recommend you update your post with a more detailed title so others are more likely to see your question.